# What does this shell script line do?

Tags: python, shell, sh

I am trying to understand the code in a shell script file (`.sh`):

```
$MY_PYTHON raw.py
```

Could you help me understand what this line does? Does it run `raw.py`?

Comment: Why are you typing random stuff in ALL CAPS?

Comment: Please be more specific. You say that the given line is from a shell script?
If so, what kind of shell script is it, where does it come from, in what context is it  called? Does it start with `#!/bin/sh`or similar as its first line?
It ($MY_PYTHON) is probably a variable that is set to a value containing the path to a  Python interpreter, like `MY_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3` and if so $MY_PYTHON would be replaced with that and would take `raw.py` as its file to run.
So basically yes, it would call the .py file.

Comment: Note that this is bad practice. Well-written scripts let the interpreter do a PATH lookup in the common case. For the uncommon case where one needs to redefine a command, shadowing it with a shell function lets the rest of the script be written as if no such redefinition was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$MY_PYTHON` is just a bash variable that stores the path to the `python` executable.

If it is not defined in your script file, it is an *environment variable*.

You can add this line to your shell script to examine its value:

```sh
echo $MY_PYTHON
```

Answer (score 1):

> It call to the py file ?

It seems so.

To be sure, could you include the definition of the `MY_PYTHON` variable?